# How to integrate Scraper API with Scrapy SitemapSpider

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

I am trying to make a Scrapy SitemapSpider and want to have each link that the spider extracts from the sitemap do a get request through the Scraper API (link to documentation: https://www.scraperapi.com/documentation#custom-headers). Do you know how I can do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the proxy url in Request's meta attribute.

```py
yield Request(
    url=url, 
    callback=self.parse, 
    meta={'proxy': 'http://scraperapi:your_key@proxy-server.scraperapi.com:8001'}
)
```

Then you can simply add Scrapy's `HttpProxyMiddleware` to your settings.

```py
DOWNLOADER_MIDDLEWARES = {
    'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpproxy.HttpProxyMiddleware': 400,
}
```

---

You could also implement your own middleware to ensure that every request goes through Scraper API.

```py
class ScraperAPIMiddleware(object):
    def process_request(self, request, spider):
        request.meta['proxy'] = 'http://scraperapi:your_key@proxy-server.scraperapi.com:8001'
```

And then enable it in settings.py or your settings object. You'll also need to enable Scrapy's HttpProxyMiddleware to make this approach work, else it won't use the proxy.

```py
DOWNLOADER_MIDDLEWARES = {
    'your_project.middleware_file.ScraperAPIMiddleware': 350,
    'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpproxy.HttpProxyMiddleware': 400,
}
```

This example uses the simplest implementation of Scraper API's [proxy mode](https://www.scraperapi.com/documentation#proxy-mode). Actually I just finished a more general purpose implementation for my own usage. It's [here](https://github.com/patkle/scrapy-snippets/tree/master/Proxies/ScraperAPI), feel free to use it.

Comment: Thanks Patrick! Instead of making my own middleware, I just set the request.meta['proxy']  variable in the process_request method that is already in Scrapy's Downloader Middleware and it seems to be working fine. Follow up question for you though - do you know what affect enabling the HttpProxyMiddleware has? My results look the same regardless if it is enabled or not.

Comment: That's true, that should work exactly the same. I'll add it to the answer. You're welcome and thank you for your comment!

Comment: @PatrickKlein may I've your permission to use `your snippet` ?

Comment: @αԋɱҽԃαмєяιcαη sure, that's why I posted it here ;) Unfortunately I lately had trouble with this using newer versions of Scrapy. Not sure why that is and not sure if you will experience the same. Will try to fix this (if necessary) as soon as I find the time.